# While inserting shapes through CSV how can I use custom shapes?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

I have created,

1. custom shape (according [how to create and edit shapes](https://desk.draw.io/support/solutions/articles/16000052874-how-to-create-and-edit-shapes-); also added a `name="my_unique_shape"` attribute to `<shape>` tag,
2. added it to "scratchpad" library,
3. named the new shape in scratchpad library; the same name as in shape attribute "my_unique_shape",

However when I want to insert shapes through CSV (using the reference CSV from [Examples: Import from CSV to draw.io diagrams](https://drawio-app.com/import-from-csv-to-drawio/)) it can't find the shape id. The CSV I'm using for test purposes is:

```
## My Unique Shape
# style: shape=%shape%;fillColor=%fill%;strokeColor=%stroke%;verticalLabelPosition=bottom;aspect=fixed;
# namespace: csvimport-
# width: 100
# height: 100
# ignore: id,shape,fill,stroke,refs
# nodespacing: 40
# levelspacing: 40
# edgespacing: 40
# layout: horizontaltree
## CSV data starts below this line
id,name,fill,stroke,shape,refs
1,Unique Name,#ffe6cc,#d79b00,my_unique_library.my_unique_shape,
```

When I change the last line to use a default shape `mxgraph.aws4.cognito` it works just fine:

```
1,Unique Name,#ffe6cc,#d79b00,mxgraph.aws4.cognito,
```

Also tried to create a New Library, adding the shape to it, and naming the shape in the library; without any luck either

#### Additional questions:

- The same question also applies how to address shapes in custom libraries?
- Are the shapes addressed by their names in the library or names in the `<shape>` XML tag?
- If by their shape names in the library, then how can I reference name with a blank?
- How do I find the name/id of shapes in stock libraries?